# How to check "#" tag is there or not in a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner in node.js so please do excuse me if my question is foolish. As we know we can use

```
var regex = /[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g;
regex.test(str);
```

to check whether a string contains special charecters or not .But what I'm asking is how to check for only a particular charecter means how can I check only presence of `#`.

I tried to do 
`var regex = /[#]/g; regex.test(str)`.
Although it's not working but are there any other method of doing this?

Comment: That's overkill. Just use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca sir could you please elaborate

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: `But it's not working.`  In what way.. `/[#]/g.test("hello#")` return true for me.

Comment: Please use the search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `includes` to check the existence of `#` in your string. You don't actually require `regex` to do that.

```js
var str = 'someSt#ring';
var res = str.includes('#');
console.log(res);

str = 'someSt#ri#ng';
res = str.includes('#');
console.log(res);

str = 'someString';
res = str.includes('#');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: note that it does not work in IE.

Comment: The Polyfill for `.includes` uses `.indexOf` anyways, so for now, sadly, `.indexOf` might be safer to use

Comment: the post is tagged `node.js` anyway, so I'd say the point is moot

Comment: `includes` give you a Boolean value so I prefer that to use instead of `indexOf` as according to this situation OP will most likely use `if-else` on this condition.

Comment: @keja yes it will not work in IE but will work on Edge.

Comment: @keja  Unless stipulated, answer on SO really should be targeting modern browsers anyway.  Any serious JS programmers toolchain should be pollyfill & transpiler capable.

Comment: i agree, also the reason i upvoted this as well as added the comment.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regex to find a single character in a string. You can use `indexOf`, like this:

```
var hasHashtag = str.indexOf('#') >= 0;
```

This returns `true` if the character is in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `indexOf`

```
str.indexOf('#') >= 0;
```